# How to dynamically access variable by name?

Tags: c#, for-loop, variables, .net-core

So I have many variable like status_CR001,status_CR002,status_CR003.

and I want to get that variable based on for looping, here's my code :

```
  for (int i = 1; i<5; i++) {
                T_Log_Result.id_log = GetUniqID();
                T_Log_Result.email_user = userID;
                T_Log_Result.bagian = "CR00"+i;
                T_Log_Result.report_status = status_CR00(i);// PROBLEM AT THIS LINE
                T_Log_Result.phase = 1;
                T_Log_Result.schedule = filter + " Mingguan";
                T_Log_Result.date_created = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                T_Log_Result.date_updated = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                _context.Add(T_Log_Result);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
```

So I dont have to do this :

```
 T_Log_Result.id_log = GetUniqID();
                T_Log_Result.email_user = userID;
                T_Log_Result.bagian = "CR001";
                T_Log_Result.report_status = status_CR001;//THIS LINE
                T_Log_Result.phase = 1;
                T_Log_Result.schedule = filter + " Mingguan";
                T_Log_Result.date_created = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                T_Log_Result.date_updated = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                _context.Add(T_Log_Result);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

 T_Log_Result.id_log = GetUniqID();
                T_Log_Result.email_user = userID;
                T_Log_Result.bagian = "CR002";
                T_Log_Result.report_status = status_CR002;//THIS LINE
                T_Log_Result.phase = 1;
                T_Log_Result.schedule = filter + " Mingguan";
                T_Log_Result.date_created = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                T_Log_Result.date_updated = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                _context.Add(T_Log_Result);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

It's easy to do that on PHP, but how about C# ?

PHP code example :

```
 $status_CR001="first";
 $status_CR002="second";
 $status_CR003="third";
 for ($i = 1; $i < 4; $i++) {
  echo ${'status_CR00'.$i};
 }
```

Comment: You probably want a `Dictionary<int, string>` or something.

Comment: Or use an `array` or `List` would, problem solved

Comment: `status_CR001` feels like it should possibly be an array? what *is* `status_CR001` (etc); can we see where they are declared?

Comment: it's not an array, it's just a variable that I created for testing.

Comment: forget the other code, I just wanna get that variable inside for loop..

Comment: Use an array or a collection rather than different variables. Then you can use the array index for the loop.

Comment: Never think about that, i'll try using array.

Answer (score 2):

A *minimal change* solution might be to write a mapping function:

```cs
    private SomeType GetStatus(int id) => id switch {
        1 => status_CR001,
        2 => status_CR002,
        3 => status_CR003,
        _ => throw new ArgumentException(nameof(id)),
    };
```

and use `GetStatus(i)` in your code.

However, it *feels* like the better solution here would be for this to be an array, i.e. `SomeType[] status_CR` (and remember that the index is zero-based, not one-based, so you'd need `status_CR[i - 1]`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection :

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    // some code ...

    // note that status can be null
    var status = this.GetType()
                     .GetField($"status_CR00{i}",
                               BindingFlags.NonPublic    // use this flag to find private members
                               | BindingFlags.Instance)? // and this one if status_CR00... is non static
                     .GetValue(this);

    // more code ...
}
```

However, I **strongly** suggest you to use arrays/list/whatever collections to achieve that

Comment: The owner of fields (status_cr00) must a class (not method) ?

Comment: @AdemAygun indeed

Comment: @AdemAygun if they are in a method, then they are "locals", not "fields", so it becomes a tautology vs "the owner of fields" (I'm going to just ignore everything related to method rewrites here - captures, iterators, async, local functions, etc)